# Identifying gradle tasks using a specific file

Tags: gradle

Given a file in a gradle project, is there any way to identify which gradle tasks touch/modify/compile... that specific file?

I am able to identify files used by a specific task using the sourceSets task (task->files), but I'd like to perform the opposite search (file->tasks).